# How can I move old commits in a branch to a new branches?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, feature-branch

I have a branch called `staging` that contains old commits that I would like to move to two separate branches.

```
A - B - C - D - E - F - G - H - I   staging
```

I would like to move commits `B` and `C` to a new branch: `feature-a`. Then move commits `D`, `E`, and `F` to a new branch: `feature-b`.

In the end my branches would look like this:

```
A - G - H - I   staging
A - B - C       feature-a
A - D - E - F   feature-b
```

The `staging` branch is public and other developers may have local versions of it. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NB: There is probably a better way, but here's one way to do it.

Creating `feature-a` is easy:

```
git branch feature-a C
```

We can create `feature-b` by creating a new branch based on `A` and then using `cherry-pick`:

```
git checkout -b feature-b A
git cherry-pick feature-a..F
```

That `r1..r2` expression is documented in the `git-rev-parse` man page:

> The .. (two-dot) Range Notation
>
> The `^r1 r2` set operation appears so often that there is a shorthand for it. When you have two commits `r1` and `r2` (named according to the syntax explained in SPECIFYING REVISIONS above), you can ask for commits that are reachable from `r2` excluding those that are reachable from `r1` by `^r1 r2` and it can be written as `r1..r2`.

Lastly, we can use `git rebase -i --root` on the `staging` branch to remove commits B-F:

```
git checkout staging
git rebase -i --root
```

---

In my test repository, this results in:

```
$ git log --oneline staging
15326ce (HEAD -> staging) This is commit I
3862020 This is commit H
a26f0bb This is commit G
9bc662c This is commit A

$ git log --oneline feature-a
b390f07 (feature-a) This is commit C
1489cd1 This is commit B
9bc662c This is commit A

$ git log --oneline feature-b
f8f3c18 (feature-b) This is commit F
0eb0b08 This is commit E
4e2ed05 This is commit D
9bc662c This is commit A
```

Comment: This is good (upvoted), I provided an alternative that does not require cherry-picking or **interactive** rebase work.

Answer (score 1):

@larsks answer is fine (upvoted), but it can also be done without any interactive work from rebase or cherry-picking. Starting from the original setup

```
git branch feature-a C # branch needs no more work
```

Right now you have:

```
* I (staging)
* H
* G
* F
* E
* D
* C (feature-a)
* B
* A
```

Then:

```
git branch feature-b F
```

Now you have:

```
* I (staging)
* H
* G
* F (feature-b)
* E
* D
* C (feature-a)
* B
* A
```

Then:

```
git rebase --onto A feature-a feature-b # place on top of commit A all commits in feature-b that are _past_ feature-a (D, E and F)
```

Now you have:

```
* I (staging)
* H
* G
* F
* E
* D
* C (feature-a)
* B
| * F' (feature-b)
| * E'
| * D'
|/
* A
```

```
git rebase --onto A F staging # place on top of A all commits that make up staging past F (G, H, I)
```

And finally you have:

```
* C (feature-a)
* B
| * F' (feature-b)
| * E'
| * D'
|/
| * I' (staging)
| * H'
| * G'
|/
* A
```